# The HMS GameServiceDemo compilation fails

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk, huawei-mobile-services

Error information: NDK solution Result: Project settings: Gradle model version = 6.1, NDK version UNKNOWN

However, the NDK has been defined in the Project Structure > SDK location > Android NDK location: android \ sdk \ ndk \ 21.0.6113669.

What is the cause of the error?

Comment: The HMS GameServiceDemo does not use and depend on the NDK. Please reset  settings and try again.

Comment: Are you using Unity?

Comment: After resetting, the same error is reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the synchronization is normal, the compilation is successful. However, if the synchronization is performed only, the APK file is not packed and generated. In this case, try **Build->Build Bundle(s)/APK(s)->Build APK(s).** The generated APK file is stored in the **project directory\build\outputs\apk\debug directory.**

Answer (score 0):

The error message "NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=6.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN" should be displayed in the Event Log, which does not affect the compilation of the project.
If the project fails to be compiled, provide the build error information.
If an error occurs, click Run build in the Build window to display the detailed error information.

Comment: It looks abnormal but no error is reported, no apk is generated under build.output

Comment: If the synchronization is normal, the compilation is successful. However, if only the synchronization is performed, the APK file is not packed and generated. Try Build->Build Bundle(s)/APK(s)->Build APK(s). The generated APK file is in the project directory\build\outputs\apk\debug directory.